# My while loop does not work

Tags: visual-c++, while-loop, integer

i want to check the user input which cant larger than 2 and smaller than 1 as well as cant be char (because the input type is int) but my code seem not working.....anyone can help me out? I tried various way but seem i still get it
update: here is part the code , source is declared as int in previous part

```
Student stu;
List<Student> list;
char id[10];
string str;
int choice;
int source;
bool ask;
while(true){
switch(menu()) {
case 1:
{
    system("cls");
    if (ReadFile("student.txt", &list)) {
        cout << "\nRead File Successfully!\n";
    }
    else
        cout << "\nRead File Failed!\n";
    system("pause");
    break;

}
case 2:
{
    system("cls");
    if(list.empty()){
        cout<<"\nThe list is empty!\n";
        break;
    }
    cout<<"\nStudent id: ";
    getline(cin,str);
    while(!isdigit(str)){
        cout<<"\nEnter [x] back to menu or re-enter the student id: ";
        getline(cin,str); 
        if(str=="x"||str=="X"){
            break;
        }
    }
    strcpy_s(id,10,str.c_str());
    if(DeleteRecord(&list, id)){
        cout<<"\nStudent successfully deleted!\n";
    }
    else
        cout<<"\nDelete student record failed!\n";
    system("pause");
    break;
}
case 3:
{
    system("cls");
    if(list.empty()){
        cout<<"\nThe list is empty!\n";
        break;
    }
    cout<<"\nStudent id: ";
    getline(cin,str);
    while(!isdigit(str)){
        cout<<"\nEnter [x] back to menu or re-enter the student id: ";
        getline(cin,str);
        if(str=="x"||str=="X"){
            break;
        }
    }
    strcpy_s(id,10,str.c_str());
    if(SearchStudent(&list, id, stu)){
        cout<<"\nStudent record found!\n";

    }
    else
        cout<<"\nStudent record not found!\n";
    system("pause");
    break;
}
case 4:
{
    system("cls");
    /*if(InsertResult("exam.txt",&list))    //Call InsertResult function
            cout<<"*INSERT RESULT SUCCESSFULLY!"<<endl;
        else
            cout<<"*INSERT RESULT FAILED!"<<endl;
    system("pause");
    break;
}
case 5:
{
    system("cls");
    /*if(InsertSubject("subject.txt",&list))    //Call InsertSubject function
            cout<<"*INSERT SUBJECT SUCCESSFULLY!"<<endl;
        else
            cout<<"*INSERT SUBJECT FAILED!"<<endl;*/
    system("pause");
    break;
}
case 6:
{
    system("cls");
    cout<<"\nWhere Do You Want To Display The Information?"<<endl;
    cout<<"\n1.Screen."<<endl;
    cout<<"\n2.File."<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    cin>>source;
    //check the input
    while(!isdigit(source)||source<1||source>2)
    {
        cout<<"\nPlease Enter A Valid Number Of Source!"<<endl;
        cin>>source;
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"\nWhich Information Do You Want To Display?"<<endl;
    cout<<"\n1.Student Information."<<endl;
    cout<<"\n2.Student Information & Past Exam Result."<<endl;
    cout<<"\n3.Student Information & Current Subject Taken."<<endl;
    cout<<"\n4.Student Information & Past Exam Result & Current Subject Taken."<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    cin>>choice;
    //check the input
        if(!isdigit(choice) || choice<1 || choice>2)
    {
        cout<<"\nPlease Enter A Valid Number Of Choice!"<<endl;
        cin>>choice;
        cout<<endl;
    }
    Display(&list,choice,source);
    system("pause");
    break;
}
case 7:
{
    system("cls");
    cout << "\nThank You For Using The Program!\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
}
}
cout << endl;
system("pause");
```

}

Comment: What does not work exactly? It does not compile? It is an endless loop? Which type is `source`? You need to be more precise!

Comment: for the first time it will block me if i enter invalid value, but for 2nd time it will let me pass although i enter any value

Comment: @Roxas Please see my updated answer which explains why that is happening.

Answer (score 1):

[isdigit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/) expects you to pass a **character** variable to it. The link I provided has an example:

```
/* isdigit example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main ()
{
  char str[]="1776ad";
  int year;
  if (isdigit(str[0]))
  {
    year = atoi (str);
    printf ("The year that followed %d was %d.\n",year,year+1);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

You don't need to use `isdigit` because you are already using a `int` variable. Thus, this is the code you need:

```
case 6:
{
    system("cls");
    cout<<"\nWhere Do You Want To Display The Information?"<<endl;
    cout<<"\n1.Screen."<<endl;
    cout<<"\n2.File."<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    cin>>source;
    //check the input
    while (source < 1 || source > 2)
    {
        cout<<"\nPlease Enter A Valid Number Of Source!"<<endl;
        cin>>source;
        cout<<endl;
    }
 }
```

Comment: i m using c++..after i change it , it still will pass after i input for 2nd time, my source is integer type

Comment: ok..but still the output is the same, it will still let me go though whatever i type in 2nd time

Comment: @Roxas Please show us **all** your code. Something is missing. Please edit your question with more code.

Comment: it become looping that whatever i enter any value it will block me

Comment: @Roxas please show the definition of the variable `source`. And is it possible to show the whole `switch` ladder?

Comment: @Roxas Great. Please see my final answer.

Answer (score 0):

> cant larger than 2

```
source > 2
```

> and smaller than 1

guessing you mean "can't be smaller than 1" `source < 1`

**demo:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    char source;  // assuming source is char!!
    cin>>source;

while(source < '1' || source > '2' || (!isdigit(source)) )
{
    cout<<"\nPlease Enter A Valid Number Of Source!"<<endl;
    cin>>source;
    cout<<endl;
}
return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing the code like this

```
while(!isdigit(source) || source < '1' || source > '2'))
    {
        cout<<"\nPlease Enter A Valid Number Of Source!"<<endl;
        cin>>source;
        cout<<endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this do-while loop Conditions,

```
   do{
      cout<<"\nPlease Enter A Valid Number Of Source!"<<endl;
      cin>>source;
      cout<<endl;
     }while(source<1 || source>2 || !isdigit(source));
```

Edited

```
char digit; // holds only one char or one digit (0 1 2 3 ...9)
int source;
cin>>digit; 
source=digit-'0'; // char to int
do{
      cout<<"\nPlease Enter A Valid Number Of Source!"<<endl;
      cin>>source;
      cout<<endl;
  }while(source<1 || source>2 || !isdigit(digit));//digit is character
```

> In **isdigit(arg)** function,pass **char argument** its working fine.

Comment: by doing this it wont let me pass although i input the right value